# Spark Scala Dataframe join and modification

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a table which has employee details and another table project which has the project details and employee id assigned.

## Employee

```
EmployeeName|Id|Address|Assigned
Joan|101|xxxx|y
```

## Project

```
ProjectCode|Number of days|Employee
XX1223|24|101
```

I have a csv file which will load the employee details in the employee table. While loading the employee details,

1. I need to identify if his employee id is assigned to the project table:

   - if the employee id is available in the project table, insert y to Assigned in the Employee table.
   - if not, insert n to Assigned in the Employee table.

I have a dataframe for Employee as,
    var employeeDF = Employee_TABLE
And,
    var employeeAssignedDF = Employee_Join_Project

At the moment, I insert to Employee first then do the join and then update Employee again. But I can do the 
     employeeDF.except(employeeAssignedDF) 
which will have a minimum number of rows.

1. Is it possible to change few of the data frame column alone?
2. I want to insert to the table only once, so when I join and do the except I should have all the records which can be inserted to DB. Is that feasible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, But not sure whether this could solve your problem or not -

```
val newDf = df.withColumn("Column", when(CONDITION, 'Y').otherwise('N'))
```

You could also use any method at the place of "when(CONDITION, 'Y')"

Comment: Is it possible to give a value here? Like,
    df.withColumn("Assigned", 'Y') ?